# Django:: Serve static files in different paths for each "app"

Tags: python, django

I would like to serve static (assets) files in the following structure (which coincidentally is the same as the local path:

```
https app/[appname]/static/* 
local_path app/[appname]/static/*
```

currently, my `urls.py` from `app` folder is

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url    

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'', 'app.views.load'),
)
```

How am I going to map the static requests to each `application` static folder?

**I know this is usually not a task for python. In production, this would probably be routed by nginx before reaching python.. But for now, I need this implemented inside django.**

Comment: How do 3rd party django apps handle it? Could you serve a specifics app static assets from WITHIN the static directory? and each app can know its STATIC_URL `/static/[appname]/` as this will already work with djangos static files

Comment: These apps are 3rd party apps so I must keep these files together within app directory.. this is coming from the project definitions, not an option.

Comment: I wish I could easily answer your question, but have you looked at other 3rd party apps? lots of them have to handle this, 2 i'm using right now are
https://github.com/darklow/django-suit/tree/develop/suit
https://github.com/applegrew/django-select2/tree/master/django_select2

Both contain static assets specific to their apps, how do they accomplish it? Is that not what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm not a django programmer, but a quick look at these repos and found nothing likely a routing to static files..